# What is mean of :+ line in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

i am beginner in `scala` and i stuck in one line. i am working in `scala` worksheet

```
     type Bit = Int

     var acc: List[Bit]=List()                        //> acc  : List[Listpr.Bit] = List()

     acc:+1                                           //> res0: List[Int] = List(1)

     "ins"+acc:+1                                     //> res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(i, n, s, L, i, 
                                                  //| s, t, (, ), 1)
     println("ins"+acc:+1)                         //> Vector(i, n, s, L, i, s, t, (, ), 1)
```

i am not getting what does mean of `:+` in `scala` and if i add `"ins"+acc:+1`  it is converting into **vector collection** in `scala`

anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Add element to the end of list. The time depend of length of list. New list is a copy of original list.`val l = List(1,2,3)` -> `l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)` `l :+ 6` => `res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the scala [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) explains it pretty well.

```
A copy of this list with an element appended.

scala> acc
res3: List[Bit] = List()

scala> acc :+ 1
res4: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> acc
res5: List[Bit] = List()
```

Basically when you do `acc:+1` it creates a new list copying elements of `acc` and adding `1` to it. No change is made to `acc`.

Well I think its a typo. I think you means ("ins" :: acc ):+1

```
scala> "ins"+acc:+1
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(i, n, s, L, i, s, t
, (, ), 1)

scala> "ins":+acc:+1
res9: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any] = Vector(i, n, s, List(), 1)

scala> ("ins" :: acc) :+ 1
res10: List[Any] = List(ins, 1)
```

`"ins"+acc:+1` prints as shown because String in scala implicitly is an `IndexedSeq`.  Doing "ins"+acc is basically `"ins"+acc.toString` which is `"insList()"`. Now `"insList()"` is of type `IndexedSeq[Char]`. Doing `:+ 1` to it will make it convert to `IndexedSeq[AnyVal]` as (`String <: AnyVal`  and `Int <:AnyVal`). Hence it prints a sequence as shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning Scala too, and there are so many crazy operators.

Basically, `:+` appends an item to a copy of the list. The `:+` operator for `List` is defined [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
def
:+(elem: A): List[A]
[use case]
A copy of this list with an element appended.

A mnemonic for +: vs. :+ is: the COLon goes on the COLlection side.

Example:

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList

scala> val a = LinkedList(1)
a: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1)

scala> val b = a :+ 2
b: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2)

scala> println(a)
LinkedList(1)
elem
the appended element
returns
a new list consisting of all elements of this list followed by elem.
Definition Classes
SeqLike → GenSeqLike
Full Signature
def :+[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

Now with your String example, it gets tricky. Scala has a `Type` called `String` (defined in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef%24)) which is an alias for `java.lang.String`. I don't see where `:+` is defined for `String`, but it seems to do analogous behavior as best it can. Append the thing on the right of the operator to the `String` but produce a [Vector](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) as a general-purpose seq. That sort of makes sense. Keep in mind also Scala's `Vector` isn't the same as Java's.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs `:+` returns "A copy of this list with an element appended". i.e. append.

`acc:+1` is straight forward returning `List(1)` which is what you would expect. Append `1` to the empty list.

`"ins"+acc:+1` is trickier since `"ins"+acc` is evaluated first and concatenates the string "acc" and the string representation of `acc` which is `` `insList() ``. Then `:+` is called on the string `insList()` which auto-magically converts it to a `List` of characters and appends `1`. Finally this gives the result `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(i, n, s, L, i, s, t, (, ), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good answers, I would like to encourage you to browse the scaladoc yourself:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

You will discover several things for yourself, and this will increase your confidence on the language and the standard library. In the amount of time that it took you to post this on stackoverflow, you might

- notice that just as :+ appends to Sequences, there is a +: that returns a copy of the list with an element prepended!
- notice "See also" that asks you to see ["Scala's Collection Library overview"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#lists) section on Lists, which turns out to be quite eye-opening, too.
- read this gem that, "Note that :-ending operators are right associative (see example). **A mnemonic for +: vs. :+ is: the COLon goes on the COLlection side**"

All the best with this wonderful, terse, expressive (and confusing!) language.